# SQL nested query under WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

One of the test questions came by with following schemas, to look for the best doctor in terms of:

1. Best scored;
2. The most times/attempts;
3. For each medical procedures (in terms of name)

[doctor] table

| id | first_name | last_name | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Phillip | Singleton | 50 |
| 2 | Heidi | Elliott | 34 |
| 3 | Beulah | Townsend | 35 |
| 4 | Gary | Pena | 36 |
| 5 | Doug | Lowe | 45 |

[medical_procedure] table

| id | doctor_id | name | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | colonoscopy | 44 |
| 2 | 1 | colonoscopy | 37 |
| 3 | 4 | ulcer surgery | 98 |
| 4 | 2 | angiography | 79 |
| 5 | 3 | angiography | 84 |
| 6 | 3 | embolization | 87 |

and list goes on...

Given solution as follow:

```
WITH cte AS(
SELECT
    name,
    first_name,
    last_name,
    COUNT(*) AS procedure_count,
    RANK() OVER(
      PARTITION BY name
      ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS place
 FROM
    medical_procedure p JOIN doctor d
    ON p.doctor_id = d.id
 WHERE
    score >= (
      SELECT AVG(score)
      FROM medical_procedure pp
      WHERE pp.name = p.name)
 GROUP BY
    name,
    first_name,
    last_name
 )
 
 SELECT
    name,
    first_name,
    last_name
 FROM cte
 WHERE place = 1;
```

It'll mean a lot to be clarified on/explain on how the WHERE clause worked out under the subquery:

1. How it worked out in general
2. Why must we match the two pp.name and p.name for it to reflect the correct rows...

```
...
 WHERE
    score >= (
      SELECT AVG(score)
      FROM medical_procedure pp
      WHERE pp.name = p.name)
 ...
```

Thanks a heap!

Comment: Working out average seems unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

Above is join with doctor and medical procedure and group by procedure name and you need doctor names with most attempt and best scored.
Subquery will join by procedure avg score and those who have better score than avg will be filtered.

Now there can be multiple doctor better than avg so taken rank by procedure count so most attempted will come first and then you taken first to pick top one

Comment: i think after going through the explanations, it is the fact that there's multiple procedures [name] that has to be taken into account thus the p.name = pp.name. thanks alot!